# Javascript: Turn a nested array into a single array using a nested for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested

This is just a simple javascript exercise that I'm working on.

I'm trying to convert this array...

```
var array = [
[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6]
];
```

into...

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

by using this nested for loop.

```
var series;
var storage = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        series = array[i][j];
        for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            storage[k] = series;
        };
    };
};

console.log(storage);
```

With an output of...

```
//Output: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Why is this the output and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {` is not required . `array[i]` will be each of element inside main array , so iterating over `array[i]` you can access each of the element

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];


var series;
var storage = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    storage.push(array[i][j])
  };
};

console.log(storage);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    series = array[i][j];
    for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        storage[k] = series;
    };
```

Seriously, here you set the same value to each element of the resulting array.

You probably need something like

```
for(let x of array) {
    for(let y of x) {
        storage.push(y)
    }
}
```

Or, if your JS machine is experimental enough, simply

```
var storage = array.flat()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to achieve what you want in one line

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

console.log(array.reduce((a, v) => a.concat(v), []));
```

As for why your code didn't work, it's mainly down to this bit

```
for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
    storage[k] = series;
};
```

It would overwrite everything in the array with the last value of `series`, which in your case would be `6`

Answer (score 1):

Array.concat can do this on its own

```
var merged = [].concat.apply([], array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [
[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6]
];
var newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   newArray = newArray.concat(array[i]); 

}
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.flat()`

Reference : [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
var array = [
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6]
];
array.flat();
// 1,2,3,4,5,6....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ES6 spread syntax like this:

```
for (let element of array){
    storage.push( ... el )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
storage = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    storage = storage.concat(array[i]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat